# How to make separate Keras model with dependent weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have to create a network with keras like in the picture below, where NN - individual neural networks.

[image]

**The problem is, that they all must have same weights**

I can't use shared layers (at least to my understanding), because then one network will get all the inputs in it and I need each to get specially one

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functional api. You can reuse a layer for different inputs. For example:

```
inp1 = Input(...)
inp2 = Input(...)
layer1 = Dense(...)
a1 = layer1(inp1)
a2 = layer1(inp2)
```

`layer1` will be applied on `inp1` and on `inp2`. It is just one layer instance, the same weights will be used for `inp1` and `inp2`.

Comment: I tried this, but, as expected, model.summery() showed that all inputs connected to one layer. In my opinion, that means all of the inputs goes into this layer -  all at once. Or I misinterpreted it ?

Comment: When you write `a1 = layer1(inp1)`, it means that `layer1` will be applied on `inp1`, and the output storded in `a1`. Not `all inputs at once` - what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: @Deniz You are misinterpreting what the diagram means, the layers are connected, but inputs do not go all at once. Weights are shared.

Comment: @AndrzejO Oh, thx. I thought about in a different way